# Error building Docker container images on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, yum, docker, dependencies, glibc

I'm trying to build a CentOS 7 Docker container from a minimal template as below

```
FROM centos:AUTO_SELECT_VERSION

RUN yum -y install yum-plugin-ovl \
 && yum -y install lsof perl file tar gzip gdb \
                   bzip2 openssh rsyslog psmisc initscripts \
                   strace tcpdump gcc

ADD rsyslog.conf /etc/rsyslog.conf
ADD elementtree-1.2.6-20050316.tar.gz /tmp/
```

but keep facing this `glibc` dependency error on my VM. Sorry I could not copy paste the error as text, but only have this at the moment

[image]

The following are the versions of `glibc` header/commons installed on my host VM

```
rpm -qa | grep glibc
glibc-devel-2.17-260.el7_6.6.x86_64
glibc-headers-2.17-260.el7_6.6.x86_64
glibc-2.17-260.el7_6.6.i686
glibc-2.17-260.el7_6.6.x86_64
glibc-common-2.17-260.el7_6.6.x86_64
```

I'm not sure if this a dependency between 32 and 64-bit packages of `glibc` installed on my VM. I'm relatively newer to building such containers, so would appreciate some feedback on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that one of your packages tries to install `glibc-2.17-260.el7_6.5.i686`, which requires the exact same version of `glibc-common`. However `glibc-common` is already installed with a slightly superior version number; whence it fails.

What can you do?

- downgrade `glibc-common` to that exact same version if it is available in your repositories
- make sure `glibc*i686` is available in your repositories with the same version as `glibc-common`; maybe installing the **epel-release** repositories will help you out with that:

install epel-release first:

```
RUN yum -y install epel-release\
    && yum -y install yum-plugin-ovl\
...
```

Comment: Will try this out right away! but I see the conflict between `i386` and `x86_64` packages of the same (from the error above ). Is it something also to consider?

Comment: well for one it is strange that he is trying to install `i686` packages, but that is not necessarily a problem. When they are part of multilib, `yum` will impose that both thave the exact same version number.